# Sum an entire column in Numbers from a different sheet?

Tags: numbers, iwork

Is there a way to do something like `Sheet1::Table1::SUM(A1:AΩ)`, where `Ω` returns the last row number on Sheet1? This would enable leaving Sheet1 with values only, no formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is dead simple: `SUM(Sheet1::Table1::A)`, or `SUM(Sheet1::Table1::ColumnName)`.